# lightning component visibility based on profile

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, profile, visibility

I am pretty new to lightning so I wanted to know if there is a way to hide a lightning component based on certain conditions. I have a requirement where there are 4 components which need to be visible to users belonging to a particular profile and should not be accessible to others.

Thanks,

Comment: in what context, lightning experience, or lightning communities?

Answer (score 5):

You can conditionally show/hide components on the page by setting the component visibility. Select your component and in the properties panel you have the flexibility to show/hide based on a field in the record or user level attributes. See below for clarity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give access to Lightning Bundle from profile.

**But you can do is rerender based on the logged in user profile.**

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Create a custom lightning record home page for each profile and assign each page to each profile.
2. Display/hide specific component, according to a field criteria on the current record.

Both scenarios are described well in this trail:

[Build a Custom Record Page for Lightning Experience](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_app_builder/units/lightning_app_builder_recordpage#)

The first scenario - under the `Roll Out Your Custom Record Page to Your Lightning Experience Users` section.

The second scenario - under the `Make Your Record Page Dynamic` section

Answer (score 0):

You may find that your User>Profile>Name is "System Administrator".
Check in Setup>Profiles.

You can also use filter logic for more complex conditions.

[image: Two filters. Show if either is true.]

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to this, too. As of Winter 21, it seems you might have to create an `Audience`...

At least, if you are trying to expose your LWC selectively within Digital Experiences (fka Communities) - within a 'Builder' page designer...

1. Select the component (or drag it onto the layout if not there)
2. Click the little upper-right chevron, see the `Audience` section, select `Assign`
   [image: assign LWC to an audience]
3. It will give an option to create an audience if you haven't any.. looks like this:
   [image]